# Динамическое изменение размеров виджета по контенту

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout

Создается виджет в  *Qt Designer*. Задача, чтобы верхний `QTextBrowser` сдвигал всё на форме и увеличивал размеры формы в зависимости от помещенного туда текста.

Выставлены ограничения `12` и `100` по высоте. После `100` появляется скролл, всё корректно, но только если удалить позиционирование размеров `Form.resize(215, 173)`.

Как в *Qt Desgner* выставить настройки, чтобы не надо было трогать руками сформированный `.ui`?

**untitled.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        #Form.resize(215, 173)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form)
        self.textBrowser.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 12))
        self.textBrowser.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 9)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
```

**main.py:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from untitled import Ui_Form

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.textBrowser.setText("Привет. Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст. ")        
       
if __name__ in '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: По умолчанию]

[image: Необходимо]

Необходимо получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

я не знаю зачем вам для каждого виджета `QVBoxLayout`?

Если убрать лишние `QVBoxLayout` и установить `stretch`, то ваш пример выглядит так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

#from untitled import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(215, 173)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form)
        self.textBrowser.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 12))         
        self.textBrowser.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser, stretch=1)
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, stretch=1) 
        
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.textBrowser.setText("Привет. Длинный текст. " * 100)
#        Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст. ")        
        

if __name__ in '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    print(w.size())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

Пускай будет по вашему.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

#from untitled import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(215, 173)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form)
        self.textBrowser.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 12))
        self.textBrowser.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textBrowser, stretch=1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, stretch=1)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 9)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.textEdit, stretch=1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3, stretch=1)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        
        
class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.textBrowser.setText("Привет. Длинный текст. " * 100)
#        Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст.  Длинный текст. ")        
       
if __name__ in '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update 2**

я предлагаю воспользоваться возможностями `QFontMetrics Class`
Класс `QFontMetrics` предоставляет информацию о метриках шрифтов.
Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html

Попробуйте набрать различные строки (короткие и длинные)
в окошке `QTextEdit`. После набора строки/строк сделайте двойной клик
(выделите любой участок текста) и все что есть в `QTextEdit`
занесется в `QTextBrowser`.

Попробуйте также изменить размеры окна.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from untitled import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(215, 173)                     
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinimumSize    )
        
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form)     
        self.textBrowser.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 25))       
        self.textBrowser.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textBrowser)    
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2) 
        
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 9)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.textEdit.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored,
                                    QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.textEdit, stretch=1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3,  stretch=1)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
 
        
class Main(QWidget, Ui_Form):      # + Ui_Form
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
#        self.ui = Ui_Form()       # -
        self.setupUi(self)         # +
        
        self.textBrowser.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)  # +
        self.textEdit.textChanged.connect(self.text_changed)                  # +
        self.textEdit.copyAvailable.connect(self.copy_available)              # +
        self.len_lines = ...                                                  # +
        
        self.text = "Hello World"   
        self.textBrowser.setText(self.text)
        
    def text_changed(self):                                                   # +
        self._textEdit = self.textEdit.toPlainText()

    def copy_available(self, _bool):                                          # +
        if _bool:
            self.textBrowser.setText(self._textEdit)
            self.func()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):                                              # +
        self.func()

    def func(self):                                                            # + !!!
        self.fontD = self.textBrowser.font()
        self.metrics = QFontMetrics(self.fontD)
        
        lines = self.textBrowser.toPlainText().split('\n')
        self.len_lines = len(lines)
        self.widthTextBrowser = self.textBrowser.size().width()   
        
        for line in lines:
            _width = self.metrics.width(line)
            if _width > self.widthTextBrowser:
                # Отрегулируйте значение, если в этом будет необходимость >>> vv
                self.len_lines += int(round(_width / (self.widthTextBrowser - 20) + 0.5, 0)) - 1
        
        # Отрегулируйте значение koef, если в этом будет необходимость 
        if self.len_lines < 2:
            koef = 23                 
        elif self.len_lines == 2:
            koef = 36
        elif self.len_lines == 3:
            koef = 50
        elif self.len_lines == 4:
            koef = 63
        elif self.len_lines == 5:
            koef = 76
        elif self.len_lines == 6:
            koef = 88   
        elif self.len_lines > 6:
            koef = 101

        self.textBrowser.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, koef))         # !!!  
        self.textBrowser.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, koef))    # !!!           

       
if __name__ in '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что это была выдержка из общего кода. В каждом Layout по несколько виджетов и Layout'ы используются и внутри, и снаружи ещё.

Comment: @WD_KMS а так пойдет? см. обновление.

Comment: Так получается, что максимальная высота около 65 только. Можно поставить self.textBrowser.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 70)) и self.textBrowser.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 170)) - и будет одинаковая высота у QTextBroswer

Comment: @WD_KMS опубликуйте пожалуйста изображение, которое вы хотите получить в результате запуска приложения.

Comment: Добавил. QTextBrowser должен растягиваться до установленной максимальной длины, если текста много. И оставаться по установленному минимуму, если текста мало.

Comment: @WD_KMS похоже на то, что я реализовал вашу задумку. Смотрите обновление.

Comment: @WD_KMS что не так?

Comment: Спасибо за идею с QFontMetrics. Я тоже в итоге остановился на ручном подсчете высоты, но без QFontMetrics. Так точнее получится, да.